# fontspec and/or xdvipdfmx can't find certain fonts

Tags: fonts, fontspec, mactex, xdvipdfmx

This morning, I updated my MacTeX installation to the 2015 install. Unfortunately, something is now having some trouble with the font (Century/Century Schoolbook) that I use most [edit: everything worked fine before]. I'm a relative amateur with TeX and couldn't fix the issue with a couple hours of Googling, so here I am. Help!

The issue appears to be that `fontspec` and/or `xdvipdfmx` (whatever that is) are having trouble finding certain fonts on the computer. So some fonts work, others just don't. My investigations suggest that the fonts that are having trouble appear to be ones that came with MS Word—all of the offenders so far were originally located in `/Library/Fonts/Windows`. I moved them to the main folder but that didn't help, so I don't know what it is that's making these specific fonts invisible or uncooperative.

I've seen two similar errors. First, e.g., with the Century font. This code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Century}

\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

Produces this error and refuses to compile/typeset:

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /Library/Fonts/Century
```

But with other fonts, e.g. Colonna, I get something slightly different. This code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Colonna}

\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

Produces this error and refuses to compile/typeset:

```
/Test.tex:5: fontspec error: "font-not-found"

!

! The font "Colonna" cannot be found.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Both examples show `Colonna`  -- I think the first one should be `Century`?

Comment: Can you compile those examples with LuaLaTeX? I know you want to use XeLaTeX - I'm not proposing a solution, it is just useful to know whether the problem is specific to XeTeX or not.

Comment: Did these fonts work before you switched to TL 2015? Have you used TeX Live Utility or `tlmgr` to update the new installation?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts! Replies.

(1) Oops! Fixed it, thanks.

(2) Umm ... I've never used LuaLaTeX before and I'm not sure how to go about it, but that makes good sense as a suggestion. I'll try to find time to look into that and post what I find.

(3) Yep, everything was fine before, and I have updated with the TeXLive Utility.

Comment: @cfr — Alright, I swapped TeXShop over to LuaLaTeX. (I just changed it in the pull-down menu top left. If there's something more I need to do to make LuaLaTeX work I missed that.) It's still not working, but interestingly enough Century now throws the fontspec "font-not-found" error instead of the "xdvipdfmx:fatal" error. So maybe the problem is specific to fontspec?

Comment: If you put the fonts back where they were in `/Library/Fonts/Windows`, what error do you get then? *How exactly did you move the fonts?* What does `file /Library/Fonts/Windows/Century*` give? (or `file /Library/Fonts/Century*` if you haven't moved it back).

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate of the linked answer, which concerns a much older problem.  This question is about a recent upgrade of a working system.  Or maybe it's just that the answer there isn't at all clear given this OP's question. Angelo's answer here is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, drove me mad. I generate documents that used the `Century Gothic` font. I upgrade my mac to El Capitan, and then reinstalled the newest TeX stuff. Since then, I could not get it to work.

Eventually I found out the fonts in my `/Library/Fonts` folder were 0 bytes, some kind of mac-thingy called "suitcase fonts". I removed my century gothic font, and installed a `.ttf` version from a windows box into the computer font store (`/Library/Fonts` again). Then everything worked like a charm!

Comment: The solution in the linked "already has an answer" did it for me. Apparently it was some sort of issue with the "suitcase" thing, so extracting the true type font and then adding it back in seems to have done the trick. Thanks so much for your help, everyone!